# What the reason i get isReject() in addOnCompleteListener() Auth Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have checked all code and it is completely the same with a properly working sample that i had implemented before. Problem is - Every time i get reject in auth listener.

For description i have two projects :

first - for test (where i have implemented auth with Firebase and it is working)

and second - my main project (where without success i am trying to implement the same code from my test project)

There is my code

User make click on <kbd>Google LogIn</kbd> button and i catch result in

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == States.GOOGLE_SIGNIN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        googleImplementation.handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

public void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        new FirebaseAuthLogIn(respond).firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
    }
}

public void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    String token = acct.getIdToken();
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null);
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
               ------>>    respond.isReject();    <-------
                    } else {
                        respond.isSuccessful();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

What am i doing wrong? What the reason is this doesn't work? In test project it is work perfectly in main project i get reject all the time...

If i forgot add something important fill free to ask me.

Comment: you are check sign in with google is enable in firebase console ?

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue with that.

Comment: @VishalPatoliya yes really i forgot to enable it in google console. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:-

Please check your permission in firebase console for login with google is enable or not !

Answer (score 2):

> `Use this method which is working for me currently in my project. Make sure to enable sign-in with google in your developer console.`

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("test", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("test", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("test", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
}
```

> `Call that function inside handleSignInResult method`.

```
if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
            //mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            //updateUI(true);
        }
```